# Need help with identifying peace lily root disease

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, diseases, rot, peace-lily

My peace lily started dying, it's leaves were turning yellow and then brown from past 2-3weeks. I speculated it to be a root rot. Today, I took out the plant from soil and along with root rot, I found these black webs in the main root bulb. For now, I thoroughly cleaned the roots and soaked the plant in 1:1 hydrogen peroxide-water solution for about an hour. Later transferred it to filtered water.
I am not sure if its just root rot or something bigger which I don't know. Do I need to treat my plant with any pesticides? If yes, please share your suggestions. [image]